# Matlab: Using csvimport to read several .csv files with a loop

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to read several .csv files in a folder with this [Matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport). I have no problem at all reading just one of 'em, but I don't know how to use 'em to read them all at once.

For a simple file, I just did this (I believe it has too many lines, but it works):

```
mkdir('Unzipped')  % create a new folder
% Choosing a file to unzip
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.zip', 'Select a compressed file'); 
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
else
   disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])
   filename=fullfile(pathname, filename);
   unzip(filename, 'Unzipped');
end
%To choose the .csv file I want to read, I use this.

[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.csv'}, 'Select a .csv file');
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
else
   disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])
   filename=fullfile(pathname, filename);
   csvimport(filename);
end
```

That works just fine, but, what if I want to read them all at once? I suppose I can use something like this:

```
files= dir('folder where files are stored\*.csv');      
num_files = length(files);
for i=1:num_files
     % MY DOUBT IS HERE
end
```

How can I write that loop's argument? the function csvimport needs to have the name of the file so it can work. How can I extract the name of a file, store it into a matrix, and then use it in csvimport(filename).

Can it be like this?:

```
csvimport(filename(i));
```

**Is there a way to store all the filenames into a vector and then use it as input for csvimport?** I believe that could solve my problem.

Any help you can provide, I'll be glad to know.

**First EDIT:**

I believe there could be a way using:

```
allFiles = dir( 'your folder' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };
```

I'll let you know if it worked out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you've stated, you want to store the filenames in an array (in this case an array of structures) and then loop through them and call `csvimport` on each of them.

```
% Get an array of all files
basepath = 'folder where files are stored';
files = dir(fullfile(basepath, '*.csv'));

% Pre-allocate data storage
data = cell(size(files));

% Import each file using it's filename
for k = 1:numel(files)
    data{k} = csvimport(fullfile(basepath, files(k).name));
end
```

You can then access the resulting data within the `data` variable. Such as:

```
disp(data{1})
```

For people who like short things...

```
data = arrayfun(@(f)fullfile(basepath,f.name), dir(fullfile(basepath,'*.csv')), 'uni', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suever. It works just fine. I'll try the other suggestions you made along with mine (I edited my first post with a possible approach) and see which ones suits best.